# SQL multi table query problem using Inner Join

Tags: sql, oracle, join, group-by, sum

I'm trying to solve this question using Inner Join but I keep getting errors

List the customer number, order number, order date, and order total for each order with a total that exceeds $500. Assign the column name ORDER_TOTAL to the column that displays order totals. Order the results by order number.

**ORDERS** table has CUSTOMER_NUM, ORDER_NUM, and ORDER_DATE

**ORDER_LINE** has ORDER_NUM, ITEM_NUM, NUM_ORDERED, and QOUTED_PRICE

**This is my solution:**

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_NUM, ORDERS.ORDER_NUM, ORDER_DATE, SUM(QUOTED_PRICE) AS ORDER_TOTAL     
FROM ORDERS     
INNER JOIN ORDER_LINE ON ORDERS.ORDER_NUM = ORDER_LINE.ORDER_NUM    
GROUP BY ORDER_NUM     
HAVING ORDER_TOTAL > 500;
```

**The error I'm getting:**

```
Error starting at line : 61 in command -    
SELECT CUSTOMER_NUM, ORDERS.ORDER_NUM, ORDER_DATE, SUM(QUOTED_PRICE) AS ORDER_TOTAL     
FROM ORDERS     
INNER JOIN ORDER_LINE ON ORDERS.ORDER_NUM = ORDER_LINE.ORDER_NUM    
GROUP BY ORDER_NUM     
HAVING ORDER_TOTAL > 500

Error at Command Line : 65 Column : 8
Error report -

SQL Error: ORA-00904: "ORDER_TOTAL": invalid identifier    
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Oracle does not allow reusing aliases defined in the `SELECT` clause in the `GROUP BY` clause. You need to repeat the expression. Also, all non-aggregated columns must appear in the `GROUP BY` clause.

So:

```
SELECT o.CUSTOMER_NUM, o.ORDER_NUM, o.ORDER_DATE, SUM(ol.QUOTED_PRICE) AS ORDER_TOTAL
FROM ORDERS o
INNER JOIN ORDER_LINE ol ON ol.ORDER_NUM = o.ORDER_NUM
GROUP BY o.CUSTOMER_NUM, o.ORDER_NUM, o.ORDER_DATE
HAVING SUM(ol.QUOTED_PRICE) > 500;
```

Note that I modified your query to use table aliases and did prefix each column with the table it belongs to; these are good practices that make the query easier to read and write, and avoid ambiguity in regard to which table each column belongs to.